# filter user list asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm wanting to filter the list of registered users based on their roles. I've managed to do it so that it shows users of one certain role but what I want to achieve is the complete opposite and show only the users who are *not* in that user group

This is the code I have:

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();

var roleUsers = RoleManager.Roles.Single(a => a.Name.Equals("Super Admin")).Users;

var list = (from r in roleUsers
            join u in users on r.UserId equals u.Id
            select u);
```

**Update**

Thanks to @sjkm I've been able to filter out the super admins with this

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();

var roles = RoleManager.Roles.Where(a => a.Name != "Super Admin").ToList();

var userList = new List<IdentityUserRole>();

foreach (var role in roles)
{
    userList.AddRange(role.Users.ToList());
}

var list = (from r in userList
            join u in users on r.UserId equals u.Id
            select u).Distinct();

return View(list);
```

My problem now is a user who is both an super admin and another role, is shown in this list so I now need to further filter down this list to remove any super admins who may be in another role

I also forgot to mention this is using asp.net identity 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to filter out the super admins who have secondary roles, fairly simple really, just get a list of user ids of super admins and remove them from the list of non-super admin users to find and remove those with the secondary role

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();

var roles = RoleManager.Roles.Where(a => a.Name != "Super Admin").ToList();

var superAdmins = RoleManager.Roles.Single(b => b.Name == "Super Admin").Users;

var userList = new List<IdentityUserRole>();

foreach (var role in roles)
{
    userList.AddRange(role.Users.ToList());
}

foreach (var superAdmin in superAdmins)
{
    userList.RemoveAll(x => x.UserId == superAdmin.UserId);
}

var list = (from r in userList
            join u in users on r.UserId equals u.Id
            orderby u.FirstName ascending
            orderby u.LastName ascending
            select u).Distinct();

return View(list);
```

No doubts this is a really rubbish and inefficient way of doing it but it does the job nonetheless but if anyone can streamline it then please be my guest

Hope this will be of some use to somebody else out there!

**Update**

Managed to streamline this by just getting the user list and removing those whose user Ids match those who appear in the Super Admin user list

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
var superAdmins = RoleManager.Roles.Single(b => b.Name == "Super Admin").Users;

foreach (var superAdmin in superAdmins)
{
    users.RemoveAll(c => c.Id == superAdmin.UserId);
}

return View(users.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var roles = RoleManager.Roles.Where(r => r.Name != "Super Admin").ToList();

var users = new List<User>();

foreach(var role in roles) {
    users.AddRange(role.Users.ToList());
}

// 'users'-List contains all the users which do not have the 'Super Admin' role
```

(For a better perfomance get all ids of the roles and select the users with a single query `Users.Where(u => rolesIds.Contains(u.Role_IDFS))`)

Comment: Comes up with error when I try to build **"Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

Comment: You should have mentioned that you work with Entity Framework. I updated the code, try now.

Comment: Still can't get it to work, getting this error now **"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MVC_CMS.Models.ApplicationUserManager>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVC_CMS.Models.ApplicationUserManager>)' has some invalid arguments"** followed by **"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVC_CMS.Models.ApplicationUserManager>"**